# How can I run custom function when post status is changed?

Tags: post-status

I can hook custom function to each of `trash_post`, `edit_post`, `private_to_publish` etc. to meet some of my requirements, but I need also to check for more possible transitions like *'pending to draft'*, *'private to draft'* and so on.

Something similar to this inexistent function:

```
if( post_status_changed($post_id) ) {
    my_custom_function();
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See [this Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions). In general the hook is `{old_status}_to_{new_status}`. (Untested) but in your case, the hook would be `pending_to_draft`:

```
 add_action('pending_to_draft','wpse45803_pending_to_draft');
 function wpse45803_pending_to_draft($post){
  //Do something
 }
```

You might want to look up the [`wp_transition_post_status`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/post.php#L2980) function. You could also use the hook: `transition_post_status`

```
 add_action('transition_post_status','wpse45803_transition_post_status',10,3);
 function wpse45803_transition_post_status($new_status,$old_status,$post){
  //Do something
 }
```

Comment: Stephen, thank you a lot! I've read about [Post Status Transitions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) before but I've missed that I can combine those statuses at will to get a hook. I'll try.  Can't vote up because of low reputation...

Comment: I think you can always up-vote, in any case you can accept an answer by clicking the tick next to it. (Please do this as it takes the question of the unanswered pile and means others with the same question can quickly find the 'correct' answer :D)